# WooCommerce - determine product category of current single product page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, categories, product

In my `header.php` I want to add title based on the category of the page.

My current code looks like this:

```
<h1 class="page-title"><?php

    if (is_category('english') || has_category('english',$post->ID)) {

        echo "music in the world of noise";

    } elseif (is_category('marathi') || has_category('marathi',$post->ID)) {

        echo "क्षितिज जसे दिसते";

    } elseif (is_category('happenings') || has_category('happenings',$post->ID)) {

        echo "Happenings";

    } elseif (is_product() && is_product_category( 'music' ) ) {

        echo "music";

    } elseif (is_product_category( 'album' )) {

        echo "albums";

    } elseif ( is_product() && is_product_category( 'workshop' ) ) {
        echo "Workshop";
    } elseif( is_product() && has_term( 'workshop' ) ) {
        echo "Workshop";
    } else {
        the_title();
    }

    ?>

</h1>
```

I want to  echo out `Workshop` in h1 if the product page is single product page AND if that product is in the `workshop` category. Same for `Music`. `is_product_category` works only on category page not on single product page.

How do I determine the category of single product and echo the relevant text. Other if statements (`is_category('english')` `has_category()`) are working except for the woocommerce pages?

Comment: Product categories are not categories, they are a terms in a custom taxonomy. Therefore `has_category("music")` needs to be replaced with [`has_term( "music", "product_cat" )`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_term)

Answer (score 4):

There is some mistakes in your code regarding WooCommerce categories:

- Functions **`is_category()`** and **`has_category()`** doesn't work with WooCommerce product categories *(WooCommerce product categories are a custom taxonomy '**`product_cat`**')*.
- Conditional `is_product() && is_product_category()` will not work together with **`&&`**, as [**`is_product()`**](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/conditional-tags/#section-7) will target single product pages and [**`is_product_category()`**](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/conditional-tags/#section-5) will  target product categories archives pages.

To target your product categories in single product pages, you need to use Wordpress conditional function [**`has_term()`**](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_term) with '**`product_cat`**' taxonomy.
 You can also target product categories archives pages at the same time in your condition, if they use the same title…

So your code (for WooCommerce product categories) is going to be something like:

```
<h1 class="page-title"><?php

//      ... / ...

    if ( is_product() && has_term( 'music', 'product_cat' ) || is_product_category( 'music' ) ) {
        echo "Music";
    } elseif ( is_product() && has_term( 'album', 'product_cat' ) || is_product_category( 'album' ) ) {
        echo "Albums";
    } elseif( is_product() && has_term( 'workshop', 'product_cat' ) || is_product_category( 'workshop' ) ) {
        echo "Workshop";
    } else {
        the_title();
    }
?></h1>
```

If you don't need to target at the same time product categories archives pages, you will have to remove in each condition statement **`|| is_product_category()`**…

Comment: Thanks for the help. I think I did try `has_term`. Let me use your code and will revert back